# How to get activity context in a viewpager's fragment if viewpager is hosted by a fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a fragment which holds a viewpager and i can not get the activity/context by calling "getActivity()" in any of the viewpager's fragments.

I have a valid context of the activity inside onCreateView and in onAttach, but not after i swiped to the fragment inside the viewpager. All the members i created inside onCreateView, which need a context, are also null (after swiping).

I tried to store the activity in a member, but this didn' t work either and i don't really like to store the context either because of possible memory leaking.

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it....

getActivity() returned null after i was starting an intent for adding an image to the fragment. After picking an image, the method "getItem(int position)" in my FragmentPAgerAdapter was called again and i was creating a new Fragment there, so "getActivity()" was then called on an unvalid fragment.

It was like:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0: return MyFragment.newInstance("MyFragment");
```

It is now like:

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
        }

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0: if (mFragment==null)
                        mFragment=new MyFragment();
                    return mFragment;
```

So now i'm returning the already created fragment and not another one.